# Removing a character from a string in a list of lists

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I'm trying to format some data for performing an analysis. I'm trying to remove  `'*'` from all strings that start with one. Here's a snippet of the data:

```
[['Version', 'age', 'language', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7', 'Q8', 'Q9', 'Q10', 'Q11', 'Q12', 'Q13', 'Q14', 'Q15', 'Q16', 'Q17', 'Q18', 'Q19', 'Q20', 'Q21', 'Q22', 'Q23', 'Q24', 'Q25', 'Q26', 'Q27', 'Q28', 'Q29', 'Q30', 'Q31', 'Q32', 'Q33', 'Q34', 'Q35', 'Q36', 'Q37', 'Q38', 'Q39', 'Q40', 'Q41', 'Q42', 'Q43', 'Q44', 'Q45'], ['1', '18 to 40', 'English', '*distort', '*transfer', '*retain', 'constrict', '*secure', '*excite', '*cancel', '*hinder', '*overstate', 'channel', '*diminish', '*abolish', '*comprehend', '*tolerate', '*conduct', '*destroy', '*foster', 'direct', '*challenge', 'forego', '*cause', '*reduce', 'interrupt', '*enhance', '*misapply', '*exhaust', '*extinguish', '*assimilate', 'believe', 'harmonize', '*demolish', 'affirm', 'trouble', 'discuss', '*force', 'divide', '*remove', '*release', 'highlight', 'reinforce', 'stifle', '*compromise', '*experience', 'evaluate', 'replenish']]
```

This should be simple, but nothing I've tried works. For example:

```
for lst in testList:
    for item in lst:
        item.replace('*', '')
```

just gives me back the same strings. I've also tried inserting an if statement and indexing the characters in the strings. I know I can access the strings. For example if I say `if item[0] == '*': print item` it prints the correct items.

Comment: read the doc. `replace` does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`string`s are immutable , and as such `item.replace('*','')` returns back the string with the replaced characters, it does not replace them inplace (it cannot , since `string`s are immutable) . you can enumerate over your lists, and then assign the returned string back to the list -

Example -

```
for lst in testList:
    for j, item in enumerate(lst):
        lst[j] = item.replace('*', '')
```

---

You can also do this easily with a list comprehension -

```
testList = [[item.replace('*', '') for item in lst] for lst in testList]
```

Comment: Thanks Anand, this works like a charm. The j, item, enumerate syntax is subtle for a novice such as myself, and will be useful down the road I'm sure. List comprehensions are one of the beautiful things about python, so thanks for including the additional solution!

Comment: Done. Thank you for filling me in on the community protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using enumerate in order to have access to list element's index when the time comes and you need to change it:

```
 for lst in testList:
      for i, item in enumerate(lst):
          if item.startswith('*'):
               lst[i] = item[1:] # Or lst[i] = item.replace('*', '') for more
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to either create a new `list` (demonstrated below) or access the indices of the old one.

```
new_list = [[item.replace('*','') if item[0]=='*' else item for item in l] for l in old_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y = []
for lst in testList:
    for a in lst:
        z = a.replace('*','')
        y.append(z)
testList = []
testList.append(y)
print testList
```

Comment: it is always helps to have some explanation

Answer (score 0):

In your code you were replacing the `*` in the dummy variable only and not effecting the list entry. Using `lstrip` will only take the `*` from the left had side of the string.

```
for x in xrange(len(testList)):
    testList[x] = testList[x].lstrip('*')
```